# onShowPress and onSingleTapConfirmed

Tags: android, events, android-event

I want to implement the following behavior:

When the user starts to single-tap my `View`, highlight the `View`. When the user finishes the single-tap (releases the touch),stop highlighting the View. Just like with simple `Button`s.

I tried to achive this with the `onShowPress` and `onSingleTapConfirmed` methods of `SimpleOnGestureListener`. Unfortunately, `onShowPress` does not get called at single-taps, but only at double-taps. How can i implement the desired behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [onDown](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html#onDown(android.view.MotionEvent)) instead of onShowPress maybe?
> Notified when a tap occurs with the down MotionEvent that triggered it. This will be triggered immediately for every down event. All other events should be preceded by this.

Comment: The problem is my `View` is scrollable and zoomable, and `onDown` is also gets called while scrolling or zooming.

Answer (score 0):

Use drawable selectors with state lists and set it as the background for your view..

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: No, this is not a solution for me. I am using a canvas-based `View`, and i'm detecting gestures within that canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i used the `onSingleTapUp` method. So this called first, i highlight the `View`, then `onSingleTapConfirmed` gets called, then i turn off the highlight. I am sure this is not the best technique, feel free to share a better one.

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing it on **down** and on up?